# Click event of buttons is not fired when it causes onChange event of textbox is fired first

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a textbox like below

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.strQuantite}">   
  <a4j:support        
    actionListener="#{tabacListCommandeAltadisDetailBean.actionListenerQuantity}" 
    event="onchange" 
  />                                            
</h:inputText>
```

I input some value into the textbox above and keep the caret inside the textbox. After that, when I continue to click a other button, the event onchange of the input text above is fired.

I want to when clicking the button, the click event is fired before.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: give the HTML code that has been generated

Comment: if you intend to fire event while typing then event must be onkeypress / onkeyup / onkeydown .i didnt quite understand what your requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to parse your English, so I'm not quite sure what your desired outcome is.  But I wonder, does your change listener need to be a4j?  Wouldn't

`<h:inputText value="#{bean.strQuantite}" valueChangeListener="#{tabacListCommandeAltadisDetailBean.actionListenerQuantity}" />`

work, since you have the button to submit the form?